# Why do I see non-parsed AngularJS expressions in the Nginx logs?

Tags: angularjs, nginx, expression

I'm working on an Angular-based SPA using Nginx and HTTPD ; I recently realized that some non-parsed AngularJS expressions are being logged in the Nginx error log :

```
2016/03/24 10:47:53 [error] 63879#0: *2639 open() "/var/www/mysite/assets/css/png/{{ client.logo }}_bw.png" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx, server: example.com, request: "GET /css/png/{{%20client.logo%20}}_bw.png HTTP/1.1", host: "www.example.com", referrer: "https://www.example.com/my-page"
2016/03/24 10:48:34 [error] 63879#0: *2789 open() "/var/www/mysite/assets/css/png/{{ src }}-small.png" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx, server: example.com, request: "GET /css/png/{{%20src%20}}-small.png HTTP/1.1", host: "www.example.com", referrer: "https://www.example.com/"
2016/03/24 10:48:37 [error] 63879#0: *2813 open() "/var/www/mysite/assets/css/png/{{ src }}-small.png" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx, server: example.com, request: "GET /assets/css/png/%7B%7B%20src%20%7D%7D-small.png HTTP/1.1", host: "www.example.com", referrer: "https://www.example.com/my-page"
```

On the website the expressions are correctly evaluated are the images shown normally, but there may be indeed a short processing time. How do I prevent Nginx from logging these expressions before they are evalutated ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `ng-src` when displaying images in your application - otherwise the browser will fire off requests for the unparsed expression to the server.

**Wrong:**

```
<img src="assets/css/png/{{ client.logo }}_bw.png" />
```

**Right:**

```
<img ng-src="assets/css/png/{{ client.logo }}_bw.png" />
```

More information: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSrc

Comment: Glad I could help! It's worth noting that the same issue applies to stuff like `href` on a link too.